# Ubuntu boot ACPI error

Tags: boot, acpi

I am getting this error while booting, and after this it always does a file system check.

ACPI error log:

[image: ACPI Error Log]

I have tried updating my BIOS, but I still have the same issue

Comment: does your device otherwise boot and run normally? if so, you can safely ignore the errors that you get at boot time.

Comment: @Esther yes it does, but the filesystem check on every boot up bothers me, also if i do fsck on my efi partition every time it shows dirty bit set

Comment: are you dual-booting with Windows?

Comment: @Esther no, my root partition , swap, efi is in a SSD and home partition in a HDD

Comment: you can clear the dirty bit manually with `fsck -a <device>`. If that's all that's causing issues, that should fix it. In general you can run `fsck` on disks if you want to fix filesystem errors.

Comment: @Esther, the dirty bit gets set on every boot

Comment: The dirty bit on FAT filesystems, in general, gets set on every mount and unset on successful unmount. If the dirty bit is set, the partition didn't get unmounted properly.